# What exactly does "Stick Sensitivity" do in Smash Ultimate custom controls?

Tags: controllers, super-smash-bros-ultimate

Super Smash Bros. Ultimate for the Nintendo Switch allows players to customize their controls.

Under "Other Settings" there is an option for **Stick Sensitivity**:

> Stick Sensitivity: **Low | Normal | High**
>
> Change how much speed is needed to perform a stick flick.

[image: Stick Sensitivity custom controls screenshot]

What exactly does this Stick Sensitivity setting control? What is a "stick flick"?

What are practical examples of in-game differences when using the Low/Normal/High settings?

How does sensitivity affect the timing or position of the stick when performing different actions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stick Sensitivity is a deceptively named control option. It has *nothing* to do with run/walk/dash sensitivity, platform drops, stick distance/movement/precision, or anything like that.

---

Stick Sensitivity *only* controls the frame window that differentiates between a Smash and a Tilt.

- **Low** stick sensitivity = **easier Tilts**
- **High** stick sensitivity = **easier Smashes**

---

After you "stick flick" your left analog, if you press "A" you will input a directional attack. Stick Sensitivity adjusts the frame window that determines if that attack will be a Smash or Tilt.

- Press "A" in the next X frames =  Smash
- Press "A" *after* those X frames = Tilt

Lengthening this frame window results in Smashes being easier to input and Tilts more deliberate.

---

```
Stick Sensitivity Frames
========================
        | L | N | H |
F-Smash | 5 | 6 | 7 |
U-Smash | 3 | 4 | 5 |
D-Smash | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

Your **optimal Stick Sensitivity** will primarily depend on whether you set your C-Stick / Right Analog to input Smash or Tilt. You will want to set Stick Sensitivity so that the *opposite class of attacks* is easier to perform with the Left Analog Stick + Attack button.

- If you use **Smash Stick**, make **A-button Tilts** easier to perform with **Low Sensitivity**
- If you use **Tilt Stick**, make **A-button Smashes** easier to perform with **High Sensitivity**

---

Set a lower sensitivity if you find it hard to Tilt with the A-button.

If you primarily Smash with the A+B shortcut, set Low sensitivity for easier Tilts.

Setting sensitivity to Low is the *closest* you can currently get to disabling Smash attack input from your A-button and Left Stick. You unfortunately cannot completely turn off Smash attacks.

References:

- https://smashboards.com/threads/all-about-stick-sensitivity.466696/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/aafl58/stick_sensitivity_is_a_lie_read_for_truth/

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure? I found it difficult to control my character at first and do things such as turn around quickly in normal sensitivity as I don't move my joystick as much which was quickly alleviated when I switched to high sensitivity.

Comment: This answer is correct for f-smash, but for d-smash it's 3/4/5 instead of 5/6/7, and for u-smash it's technically also 3/4/5 but it almost doesn't matter because under normal conditions you jump after 3 anyway. Not sure how you'd edit to include.

Comment: @Toomai great info. Have a source I can link when I edit? Does this have a page on the SmashWiki?

Comment: This sheet is public now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdH2L0xi8dO6jyPCcO5e5-8j7SGzezxkeZuF1uP8uOw/edit#gid=1341015828

Answer (score 4):

In Japanese, the Stick Sensitivity option is titled はじき入力 meaning **"Flick Input"**.

The options are:

- はじき入力 **"Flick Input"**.

  - 出にくい "Hard to input" (Low)
  - 普通 "Normal"
  - 出やすい "Easy to input" (High)

This seems to indicate that "Stick Sensitivity" is a bad translation of the Japanese original. It's much easier to understand "easy" and "hard" settings for "Flick Input" aka Smash Attacks.

[Source - user Logo121 on Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/aafl58/stick_sensitivity_is_a_lie_read_for_truth/ecso2qs/)